# Using TinyMCE-react

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

I'm using `tinymce-react` and I'm trying to load `modern` theme and `lightgray` skin.

```
<Editor
  initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
  init={{
    theme_url: "/themes/modern/theme.min.js",
    skin_url: "/skins/lightgray",
    height: 120,
    menubar: false,
    skin: "lightgray",
    theme: "modern",
    mobile: {
      theme: "mobile",
      plugins: ["autosave", "lists", "autolink"]
    },
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
      "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code"
    ],
    toolbar: "bold underline italic | bullist numlist | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link"
  }}
/>
```

I'm getting `theme.min.js:1 Uncaught module [b] returned undefined` in file `theme.min.js:1`.

I have copied folders `plugins`, `themes` and `skins` to `/public` folder.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to load TinyMCE 4 or TinyMCE 5?

Comment: I'm using TinyMCE 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to load a skin that no longer exists in TinyMCE.  The default skin in TinyMCE 5 is called `oxide` and there is no skin called `lightgray`.

In most cases you don't need to state the skin in the configuration if you want to use the default.  I would try removing all references to the skin in the configuration and only add back the `skin` or `skin_url` option if TinyMCE cannot locate its skin on its own (which is rare).

The same holds true for the `theme` settings in TinyMCE.  The default theme in TinyMCE 5 is called `silver`.  The editor should be able to locate and load that on its own as well.